# C# client - securing REST authentication tokens on client machine

Tags: c#, wcf, security, rest

Question i'd like to discuss about.

We have REST services (WCF) that after logon - a token is received and is sent to the client.
HTTPS is of course defined.

each request sends this token in the "Authorization" header.

The thing is, that if someone dumps the memory, he will be able to get the token and use it as he wishes.

we can secure this token only until the send, as we need to convert it to a C# string - which, can't be explicitly disposed.

so, there are 2 problems with this approach:

1. The garbage collector moves managed objects, and this string can be duplicated in memory
2. strings are managed with an internal table. they are immutable and can't be cleared on request.

is there a recommended way of securing the token? maybe buffering the headers each request 1 character at a time?

Would love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a little confusing, are you the client/consumer, or the service/provider?

If you're the provider, you should be more concerned about having HTTPS enabled, you wouldn't believe how easy it is to steal tokens over the clear web and if your service is compromised, then having the memory dumped is still the least of your problems.

That said, what you're looking for is `SecureString` you can find more information on it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And here's a small example of how to make it work....

```
public void Example()
{
    SecureString secureString = ConvertToSecureString("abc");
    string normalString = ConvertToString(secureString);
    Console.WriteLine (normalString);
}

// Secure it
public  SecureString  ConvertToSecureString(string password)
{
    SecureString secureString = new SecureString();

    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) 
    {
        secureString.AppendChar(c);
    }

    return secureString;
}

// Unsecure it
public string ConvertToString(SecureString securePassword)
{
    IntPtr unmanagedString = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        unmanagedString = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(securePassword);
        return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(unmanagedString);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(unmanagedString);
    }
}
```

It's probably worth checking out the [DPAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) whilst you're on the subject too...

Here's one of my utility classes that makes use of it

```
public void DpapiExample()
{
    // Adds a level of entropy to our encryption making our encrypted data more secure
    string entropy = "603e0f3a0ef74faf93b5e6bc2c2f7c358107";
    var dpapi = new Dpapi(entropy);

    string textToEncrypt = "I'm a secret";

    string encryptedText;
    dpapi.TryEncrypt(textToEncrypt, out encryptedText);
    Console.WriteLine ("Encrypting");
    Console.WriteLine (textToEncrypt);
    Console.WriteLine (encryptedText);

    string decryptedText;

    dpapi.TryDecrypt(encryptedText, out decryptedText);

    Console.WriteLine ("\r\nDecrypting");
    Console.WriteLine (encryptedText);
    Console.WriteLine (decryptedText);  
}

public class Dpapi
{
   private readonly byte[] entropy;

   public Dpapi(string entropy)
   {
       this.entropy = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(entropy);
   }

   public Dpapi(string entropy, Encoding encoding)
   {
       this.entropy = encoding.GetBytes(entropy);
   }

    public bool TryDecrypt(string encryptedString, out string decryptedString)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(encryptedString))
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException("encryptedString");
       }

       decryptedString = string.Empty;

       try
       {
           byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString);
           byte[] decryptedBytes = ProtectedData.Unprotect(encryptedBytes, this.entropy, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
           decryptedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
       }
       catch
       {
           return false;
       }

       return true;
   }

   public bool TryEncrypt(string unprotectedString, out string encryptedString)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(unprotectedString))
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException("unprotectedString");
       }

       encryptedString = string.Empty;

       try
       {
           byte[] unprotectedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unprotectedString);
           byte[] encryptedData = ProtectedData.Protect(unprotectedData, this.entropy, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
           encryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
       }
       catch
       {
           return false;
       }

       return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i'll update - i'm the client.
HTTPS is already defined by default. so i'm afraid of someone dumping the memory.

secure string will not help, as it's encrypted locally, and can't be sent to the server...

Comment: and about your 2nd DAPI solution - once the secret is stored in a C# string, it's vulnerable to memory dumps

Comment: As I said, if you're server is compromised, the least of your worries are memory dumps, it's part of the Microsoft Data Protection API, so technically it isn't my solution. Most of those cookies you see flying back and forth from ASP.NET solutions boil down to DPAPI. As a client, there isn't much that you can do. If a user's machine is compromised, then that really is the end of it, no matter what you try someone determined enough will find it. I.e. if I have control over the machine enough to do a memory dump, I'll have enough to reverse proxy with fake certs and still render the SSL useless.

Comment: I understand, but we are trying to make it harder for the attacker to retrieve this token.

for example, if we used C++ - we could encrypt this token with a dynamic key created each time, use it to make the REST call, and then delete it from memory. - this will make the key live inside the memory encrypted for a really short time.  because of C# strings / GC algorithm - we cannot delete that string from memory. so i'm still searching for other solution..

Comment: I think you've already spotted the solution, if you can do it in C++, do it in C++, do all of the actual rest calls from the C++ lib and let the C# application interface with it for everything else.

Comment: I still want to discuss and see if there's another less-costy solution - maybe to integrate with the existing HttpWebRequest, etc...
maybe stream somehow the header? byte by byte?
another interesting solution?

Comment: To do that, you're going to have to use sockets directly. HttpWebRequest only allows you to read from the body of the response as a stream, byte by byte. Again all of this is a false sense of security because it still doesn't prevent an attacker who has control of a machine to reroute traffic. HTTPS will only prevent man in the middle attacks.

Comment: Well, i don't think it's a false sense of security.
when an attacker has the machine, we could also make it harder for him to get sensitive data.
on client machine you can't be 100% secured, but why not being over 0%?

we will use socket directly probably.
Thanks

Comment: It's generally because the cost of implementing it outweighs most of the benefits, it's too much work for too little gain. I suppose if it's an application developed for the finance industry or similar, then it could make sense depending on the requirements. However, your security should be focused on the service point with things such as two-factor auth, expiring tokens, even expiring password policies. And you haven't done 0%, you've implemented SSL, the same level of protection that your Bank offers you every time you sign on to your accounts online. I hope you see where I'm coming from :)

Comment: I totally see your point :)
we do use token expiry.
we already have a good implementation that reduces validity time in case someone steals the token.
we will indeed though want to make it harder for the client-only attacker to use that token.
thanks for your input! we will look into using C++ implementation for the network layer.